# How to solve " No mapping for GET HTTP URL"

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am working on webapp using spring mvc + hibernate. I am getting a warning as

```
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-1) No mapping for GET /ProjectFE/deleteproducts/
```

here's my code for Controller mapped deleteproducts:

```
@DeleteMapping(value="/deleteproducts/{productId}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable("productId")int productId) {
        IProductsDAO ip = new ProductsDAOImpl();
        boolean b = ip.deleteProduct(productId);
        if(b)
            return "success";
        else
            return "deleteproducts";
    }
```

jsp view:

```
   <body>
<form id="update product form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteproducts" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="product Id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Id</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="productId" class="form-control" id="productId" placeholder="Enter the product Id you want to delete">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
</body>
```

DAOImplementation for delete method call:

```
public boolean deleteProduct(int productId)
    {
        boolean b = true;
        try
        {
            sess.beginTransaction();
            Products p = (Products)sess.load(Products.class, new Integer(productId));
            sess.delete(p);
            sess.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            sess.getTransaction().rollback();
            b = false;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

[image: Project structure for Front End]

can this issue be occurring because of the `/{productId}` part ? Please some one help!!
Thankyou.

[image: Exception generated when hitting the url]

Comment: I found your problem. I updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a controller to go to `deleteproduct.jsp` page. So write a controller like

```
@GetMapping(value="/delete")
    public String deleteProduct() {
            return "deleteproducts";
}
```

So hit `/delete` to got to page then do as you want.

Change your `@DeleteMapping`  to `@GetMapping`. And use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`. So your controller will be like

```
   @GetMapping(value="/deleteproducts")
    public String deleteProduct(@RequestParam(value="productId")String productId) {
        IProductsDAO ip = new ProductsDAOImpl();
        boolean b = ip.deleteProduct(Integer.parseInt(productId));
        if(b)
            return "success";
        else
            return "deleteproducts";
     }
```

And write your form like

```
 <form id="searchForm" class="form-horizontal" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteproducts">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input name="productId" placeholder="Delete product with id" class="form-control productId"
                                   type="text">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                               <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                               </button>
                             </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Thankyou so very very very much, this code worked perfectly fine for me, sorry for the late reply

Comment: @Mob_Abominator My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get an endpoint which doesn't exists. Why?
When you specify an **endpoint** `/some_end_point` and you trying to reach it with http protocol, it will expect you to specify the **request method** (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE / etc...).

When you have those 2 parameters `/some_end_point` + `POST` you need to map it in your server side like this -> `@PostMapping("/some_end_point")`.
If the client (or another server) will try to reach `/some_end_point` + `GET` it will fail because it doesn't exists, only `/some_end_point` + `POST` exists, therefor you have to add another endpoint which will be `@GetMapping("/some_end_point")` and so on.

Comment: Yeah I figured something was fishy about that as you and @Avijit Barua pointed out, So I fixed the issue, Thankyou btw.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a GET request,
 but you annotated with @DeleteMapping - which expects a DELETE request.

Comment: But the deletemapping doesn't take a method parameter anyways, so why I'm getting this problem ? where do I need to change my code ?